# How to add additional arguments to existing decorator with custom decorator

Tags: python, python-decorators

I know my question sounds a bit silly, but there is an existing decorator from a library that can either take a kwarg or not. I would like to pass this parameter in when a certain condition is achieved. So my initial thought was to write a decorator which will wrap up this function. But I have no idea if this is possible in Python.

So for example this is the original decorator:

```
@existing_decorator('This is argument')
```

And if a certain condition is called it needs to be called like:

```
@existing_decorator('This is argument', additional=False)
```

And I imagined my final result to be something like:

```
@check_condition(existing_decorator('This is argument'))
```

I tried writing a custom decorator:

```
def check_condition(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if is_production():
            return f(additional=False, *args, **kwargs)
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

This works when condition is False, but will return the following error when condition is true and argument should be included:

```
TypeError: wrapper() got an unexpected keyword argument 'doc'
```

Comment: You would need to defer execution of the wrapped decorator, so you can pass any arguments at the appropriate time, e.g. `@check_condition(existing_decorator, ('This is argument',))`.

Comment: Why not just `@existing_decorator('This is argument', additional=not is_production())`?

Comment: @chepner because this breaks the original function. If additional=False it triggers one condition and if it's set to True it breaks the function since it expects a different data type.

Comment: If it accepts `False` but not `True`, this sounds like a very strange interface. What, *exactly*, does `additional` accept? I still contend that you don't need another decorator, just a way to determine an appropriate value for the keyword argument. (If nothing else, you can select `d = {'additional': False}` or `d = {}`, then call `@existing_decorator('This is argument', **d)`, if it really distinguishes between having and not having a keyword argument named `additional`.)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not a great idea.

If you are happy with the value of `additional` being set during **decoration**, then you can construct that fairly easily, but then you might as well use the suggestion by @chepner of evaluating your argument for `additional` during decoration as well, i.e. `@existing_decorator('This is argument', additional=not is_production())`. But that is not necessarily sensible.

For the sake of argument, let's just have some simple implementation of `existing_decorator` that we can work with like this:

```py
from collections.abc import Callable
from functools import wraps
from typing import TypeVar
from typing_extensions import ParamSpec


_P = ParamSpec("_P")
_R = TypeVar("_R")


def existing_decorator(
    argument: str,
    /, *,
    additional: bool = True,
) -> Callable[[Callable[_P, _R]], Callable[_P, _R]]:
    def decorator(function: Callable[_P, _R]) -> Callable[_P, _R]:
        @wraps(function)
        def wrapper(*args: _P.args, **kwargs: _P.kwargs) -> _R:
            print(f"{argument=} {additional=}")
            return function(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

If you want to avoid repeating yourself with that additional keyword argument and just want to have a convenience wrapper, you could do something like this:

```py
...

global_state: bool = False


def conditional_decorator(
    argument: str,
    /,
) -> Callable[[Callable[_P, _R]], Callable[_P, _R]]:
    return existing_decorator(argument, additional=global_state)


@conditional_decorator("foo")
def f(x: int) -> bool:
    return x % 2 == 0
```

The problem is that now, if `global_state` changes *after* decoration, it does not affect the behavior of the wrapped function:

```py
f(1)  # argument='foo' additional=False
global_state = True
f(1)  # argument='foo' additional=False
```

This is because the original decorator passes the `additional` argument to the definition of the inner wrapper immediately

Technically, you *could* define your own decorator in such a way that it defers *construction* of the inner wrapper until the point of execution. (This may be what @jonrsharpe meant.) This is a bit more involved, but not by much:

```py
...

global_state: bool = False


def conditional_decorator(
    argument: str,
    /,
) -> Callable[[Callable[_P, _R]], Callable[_P, _R]]:
    def decorator(function: Callable[_P, _R]) -> Callable[_P, _R]:
        @wraps(function)
        def wrapper(*args: _P.args, **kwargs: _P.kwargs) -> _R:
            decorated_function = existing_decorator(
                argument,
                additional=global_state,
            )(function)
            return decorated_function(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator


@conditional_decorator("foo")
def f(x: int) -> bool:
    return x % 2 == 0
```

Now the behavior changes, if `global_state` changes:

```py
f(1)  # argument='foo' additional=False
global_state = True
f(1)  # argument='foo' additional=True
```

But the problem is that you are now causing quite a bit of additional overhead for *every* call of `f`. I have not tested/benchmarked this, but you are doing decoration *and* execution of the original function with every call to `f`. This might be worth looking into before you implement this for yourself.